# How do I prove that something is a subspace and an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let φ : V → W be an isomorphism of vector spaces V and W. Let U ⊆ V be a subspace of V. Let φ(U) = { φ(u) | u ∈ U } ⊆ W. Prove that φ(U) is a subspace of W and that U is isomorphic to φ(U).

I know that a linear transformation T from V to W is an isomorphism if and only its kernel is 0 and that the image of T = W. 
Other than than I'm lost and don't know where to go from here.

Comment: What are your attempts for attacking this problem?

Comment: As you are new to the site you might appreciate this mathjax tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: So why not try showing that the kernel is 0?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\phi(U) = \{ \phi(u) | u \in U \}$ is a subspace it needs to be shown that it is closed under linear combinations. To this end let $\phi(u_1), \phi(u_2) \in \phi(U) $ and $\lambda$ an element of the underlying field.

Observe, $\phi(u_1) + \lambda \phi(u_2) = \phi (u_1 + \lambda u_2) \in \phi (U) $.

For the isomorphism part, define a map $\psi : U \rightarrow \phi(U) $ by $\psi (u) = \phi(u) $.

The linearity of $\psi$ follows from the linearity $\phi$.

The kernel of  $\psi$ is the kernel of $\phi$ and hence zero.

The range of $\psi$ is $\phi(U)$.

Hence  $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The question as written has a very silly answer:

If $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, then $\varphi(U) = W$.  Of course, $W$ is a subspace of itself.  Since $\varphi:U \to \varphi(U)$ is an isomorphism, the two spaces are by definition *isomorphic*.

I suspect that we are *meant* to assume that $\varphi$ is injective rather than an isomorphism.

Comment: I don't think it follows that $\phi (U) =V$, the isomorphism  in the OP's question is from $V $ to $W$ and $U $ is only assumed to be a subspace of $V$.

Comment: @Bysshed read at the end of the question: "$T$ is an isomorphism ... the image of $T$ = $W$".

Comment: I don't understand.  Shouldn't you have written if $\phi :V \rightarrow W $ is an isomorphism then $\phi (V) = W$ and not  $\phi (U) = V$ ? Where $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: @Bysshed oh, yeah. I misread your comment.